# Homebrew, NPM and local project directories

Tags: terminal, homebrew, npm

I understand that using Homebrew is useful as some packages are necessary to be installed globally, but I don't understand the point in using Homebrew when you still have to install NPM at the local project directory level?

I need NVM, Gulp and NPM.

Comment: I’m not sure I follow. You wouldn’t _install NPM_ per project. You would use NPM to install the project’s dependencies.

Comment: Precisely why the need to install `npm install --save-dev gulp` when you have already have NPM installed globally via Homebrew?

Comment: Because you are _not installing NPM_. You are _using NPM_. Maybe this topic is better suited for [chat].